# using http package in flutter for networking APIs is a good practice OR its better to use Retrofit, chopper or dio?

Tags: flutter, retrofit, flutter-dependencies

Actually I want to know which package is more beneficial from the user perspective, if there are other advantage pls let know in the comments. THANK YOU

Comment: it depends on what you are more comfortable with, i used `http` `chopper` and `dio`in my opinion i like to use `dio` , cuz it has lot of options and you can write code more clear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the user's (consumer's) perspective, `http`/`dio`/etc doesn't matter at all.

From a developer's perspective (my experience), it has been easier to handle exceptions with the `dio` package than using `http`. I had a lot of frustration trying to catch HTTP Response 500 when I was using `http`, and my app keeps on crashing even though my code had a `try`/`catch`. Trying to add timeouts in my `http` code has been especially difficult. But with `dio`, they have a built-in solution (`connectTimeout`).

Also in general, writing networking code with `dio` (I haven't tried `Chopper` or `Retrofit`) is faster and easier than writing code using `http`.

Comment: what version of Dio have you tried? Because I'm thinking on change because Dio throws the assureDioError error when the server return 400 or 500.

Comment: You might be lacking a catch for the errors that you wanted

Comment: Chopper supports convertor and interceptor which are mostly good enough. Dio has much more functionality and better documentation.

Answer (score 1):

http is pretty simple - good for building demo or small project.

Chopper supports convertor and interceptor which are mostly good enough in most case. Plus, it has chopper_generator for generating part file. which is helpful and time-saving.

Dio has much more functionality and better documentation. A powerful Http client for Dart, which supports Interceptors, Global configuration, FormData, Request Cancellation, File downloading, Timeout etc. Chinese dev community love using this.